# In $n$ trials, what's the probability of that in at least $n_1<n$ we have $X\geq 1$?

Tags: probability

Let's imagine we have $X\sim f$, where $X$ is the number of occurrences in 1 trial.

In $n$ trials, what's the probability of that in at least $n_1<n$ have $X\geq 1$?

I'm thinking of doing $Z=$ number of trials with events, i.e. $Z\sim Bin(P(X\geq 1), n)$ and then calculate $P(Z\geq n_1)$. Am I correct?

Comment: Please tell us what is $f$.

Comment: @uniquesolution f is an 'ad-hoc' discrete distribution.

Comment: So we may consider that $Pr[X\geq 1]$ is equal to some unknown constant I suppose ?

Comment: @Zubzub  we can $P(X=x)$ is known for any $x$ in support. I've added some thoughts of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I will suppose that we have a sequence or random variables $X_i,\ i=1...n$ i.i.d. and that $\Pr[X_i \geq 1] = p$.

We can then define $Y_i = [X_i \geq 1]$, which means $Y_i = 1$ if $X_i \geq 1$, else $Y_i = 0$. We also define $Y=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Y_i$.

We are therefore interested in $\Pr[Y \geq n_1]$.

Clearly $Y \sim Binomial(n,p)$. Hence $\Pr[Y = k] = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$. Summing for all $k \geq n_1$ :
$$
\Pr[Y \geq n_1] = \sum_{k=n_1}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}
$$

Comment: +1. Please do not hesitate to use `\Pr` and to use punctuation signs where they are needed.

Comment: @Did I didn't know that `\Pr` was a thing. Thanks for the edit !

Comment: zub, thanks for the confirmation ;)